# How to get the value of an array based on its name?

Tags: php, xml

I have some xml data formatted like so:

```
<ADDITIONALINFORMATION>
     <ITEM>
        <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
        <NAME>Some Name Here 1</NAME>
        <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
        <VALUE>123</VALUE>
     </ITEM>

     <ITEM>
        <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
        <NAME>Some Name Here 2</NAME>
        <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
        <VALUE>abc</VALUE>
     </ITEM>

     <ITEM>
        <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
        <NAME>Some Name Here 3</NAME>
        <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
        <VALUE>456</VALUE>
     </ITEM>

     <ITEM>
        <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
        <NAME>Some Name Here 4</NAME>
        <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
        <VALUE>def</VALUE>
     </ITEM>
</ADDITIONALINFORMATION>
```

I am looping through the data using:

```
foreach($listing->ADDITIONALINFORMATION->ITEM as $item) {

        if ($item->NAME == 'Some Name Here 3') {
             $val = ''; 
                 echo '';
        }
}
```

How do I get the value of "Some Name Here 3"?

I cannot use something like $item[3] since there are various numbers of items.

Comment: I don't understand: which value are you trying to get?is it `456`?

Comment: `echo $item->VALUE;` if the statement is true..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a job for Xpath if you ask me (or kojiro), however you could do it exactly like you do it already, you only need to output your value:

```
...

$val = $item->VALUE;
echo $val;

...
```

Using xpath would you spare to iterate over all elements as the query is executed already and gives you a more specific result already:

```
$name  = 'Some Name Here 3';
$query = sprintf('//ITEM[NAME=%s]/VALUE', xpath_string($name));
list($value) = $listing->xpath($query) + [NULL];
echo $value;
```

The full example:

```
<?php
/**
 * @link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24370072/how-to-get-the-value-of-an-array-based-on-its-name
 */

$buffer = <<<XML
<LISTING>
    <ADDITIONALINFORMATION>
        <ITEM>
            <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
            <NAME>Some Name Here 1</NAME>
            <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
            <VALUE>123</VALUE>
        </ITEM>

        <ITEM>
            <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
            <NAME>Some Name Here 2</NAME>
            <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
            <VALUE>abc</VALUE>
        </ITEM>

        <ITEM>
            <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
            <NAME>Some Name Here 3</NAME>
            <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
            <VALUE>456</VALUE>
        </ITEM>

        <ITEM>
            <MULTIPLEVALUES>0</MULTIPLEVALUES>
            <NAME>Some Name Here 4</NAME>
            <VALUEARRAY></VALUEARRAY>
            <VALUE>def</VALUE>
        </ITEM>
    </ADDITIONALINFORMATION>
</LISTING>
XML;

/**
 * xpath string handling xpath 1.0 "quoting"
 *
 * @link http://hakre.wordpress.com/2013/07/11/mitigating-xpath-injection-attacks-in-php/
 *
 * @param string $input
 *
 * @return string
 */
function xpath_string($input) {

    if (false === strpos($input, "'")) {
        return "'$input'";
    }

    if (false === strpos($input, '"')) {
        return "\"$input\"";
    }

    return "concat('" . strtr($input, array("'" => '\', "\'", \'')) . "')";
}

$listing = simplexml_load_string($buffer);

foreach ($listing->ADDITIONALINFORMATION->ITEM as $item) {
    if ($item->NAME == 'Some Name Here 3') {
        $val = $item->VALUE;
        echo $val;
    }
}

$name  = 'Some Name Here 3';
$query = sprintf('//ITEM[NAME=%s]/VALUE', xpath_string($name));
list($value) = $listing->xpath($query) + [NULL];
echo $value;
```

Answer (score 1):

This sounds like a job for xpath:

```
//ITEM[NAME="Some Name Here 3"]
```

would fetch the desired element node. Both [DOMDocument](http://www.php.net//manual/en/class.domxpath.php) and [SimpleXMLElement](http://www.php.net//manual/en/simplexmlelement.xpath.php) support xpath. I'll leave it to you to choose which one you want to use.

Answer (score 1):

use string compare function and get value of that element...

```
foreach($listing->ADDITIONALINFORMATION->ITEM as $item) {
    if (strcmp($item->NAME,'Some Name Here 3') == 0) {
         $value = $item->VALUE;
    }
}
```